# set FLASK_DEBUG=1 not working on Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, flask

I'm building a Flask application and my file "**helloworld.py**" is:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/home')
def hello_world():
    return 'Home!'

@app.route('/about')
def about_us():
    return 'aboutus!'
```

My Flask code after activating venv:

```
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

Changes made to my "**helloworld.py**" file doesn't get automatically updated. I still have to restart it manually as I change anything in the code.

There is no error thrown but the changes simply don't reflect in the browser.
Why is the debug mode not working, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The syntax for setting environment variables is different in PowerShell, use `$env:`.

```
> $env:FLASK_APP = "helloworld.py"
> $env:FLASK_DEBUG = "1"
> flask run
```

`set` is used for Windows CMD.

```
> set FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

`export` is used by most other shells, like Bash and Zsh, such as on Linux and MacOS.

```
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Answer (score -1):

If your OS is Windows, you can make use of VSC terminal an run the same code

```
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

Make sure you are only making changes inside py file,  not in the terminal, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

if you are on Linux, use 'export' command instead of 'set'
and yes, its not working on power shell use CMD, but even this did not work properly.so I had to use embedded terminal. but the good thing is that you can use normal CMD(not PowerShell) as embedded terminal.
so the solution is, do not use PowerShell.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.